# Warnings in libraries during signing app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

[image]

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.hello"
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 21
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/facebook.jar')
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
        compile project(':gcmv')
        compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    }
```

Today when i am signing my app with a proguard it show too much warning in my libraries.
so because of warning i am unable to generate my signed apk file.
So is there any way to use "dontwarn" in my gradle file.

Comment: Hard to tell without the warnings !

Comment: @BastienViatge aaded the error pic.check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using picasso library.

Try to add this line in your proguard file. ( `proguard-rules.pro` in your app module )

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

Comment: now after this one more warning it showing.

Warning:can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])

Comment: This answer solve picasso problem with proguard and this new warnings are not related to picasso it's better to ask it in another question and give us more details

Answer (score 2):

As per the [ProGuard documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass):

> The standard Android build process automatically specifies the input
>   jars for you. Unfortunately, many pre-compiled third-party libraries
>   refer to other libraries that are not actually used and therefore not
>   present. This works fine in debug builds, but in release builds,
>   ProGuard expects all libraries, so it can perform a proper static
>   analysis. For example, if ProGuard complains that it can't find a
>   java.awt class, then some library that you are using is referring to
>   java.awt. This is a bit shady, since Android doesn't have this package
>   at all, but if your application works anyway, you can let ProGuard
>   accept it with "-dontwarn java.awt.**", for instance.

As stated, if it works well in debug, you can use `-dontwarn` as a class filter:

> Specifies not to warn about unresolved references and other important
>   problems at all. The optional filter is a regular expression; ProGuard
>   doesn't print warnings about classes with matching names. Ignoring
>   warnings can be dangerous. For instance, if the unresolved classes or
>   class members are indeed required for processing, the processed code
>   will not function properly.